# Trying to pass data from form to page but getting " " is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to build a node app. I have my routes built properly and , all my dependencies installed properly but when trying to load the ("/) "homepage" I get "newPost" is not defined.The ("/new) page works fine, here is what my code looks like. I've also properly linked to the Schema route. Thank you in advance!

```
  var express= require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var Post = require("./models/post");



app.set("view engine","ejs")
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/blog")

//=================================================
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    Post.find({},function(err,foundPost){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
        res.render("homepage",{post:newPost});  <--- this is the problem
        }
    })

});

app.get("/new",function(req,res){
    res.render("post/new")
});


app.post("/",function(req,res){
    var title= req.body.title;
    var image= req.body.image;
    var description = req.body.description;
    var fullPost ={title:title,image:image,description:description};
    Post.create(fullPost,function(err,newPost){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            res.redirect("/")
        }
    })

})
```

Comment: Change the line `res.render("homepage",{post:newPost});` to `res.render("homepage",{post: foundPost}); `

Comment: Thank you so much for catching that lol you are a champ! silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is telling you exactly the issue

> I get "newPost" is not defined

`newPost` doesn't exist here....

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    Post.find({},function(err,foundPost){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
        res.render("homepage",{post:newPost}); 
        }
    })

});
```

Did you mean to use `foundPost`?

Comment: Not a problem, it happens to the best of us! JavaScript errors can be red herrings sometimes - but just make sure you eliminate that first :)